# Is there a way to display private information from an Node/Express server on a mutltiplayer HTML5 canvas game with socketIO?

Tags: express, canvas, socket.io, multiplayer

I've been trying to develop an online canvas game with Node/Express and socketIO, and everything is going well as long as the data I want to display stays public, that is, every player can see it, but so far I haven't been able to privately display an object that only one player could see.

I can ID each player's browser using socketIO, but haven't been able to find a way to send data exclusively to as specifically ID'd browser without displaying it publicly on the canvas.

Is there even a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

// sending to individual socketid (private message)

```
io.to(socketId).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```